# Getting routing parameter values to the Backbone render function

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I have a route set up like this:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes: {
                    "items": "getItems", // matches http://example.com/#anything-here
                    "/*": "showAll",
                    "edit/:id" : "editItem",
                    "save/:id" : "saveItem",
                    "delete/:id" : "deleteItem"
                }
            });
            // Initiate the router
            var app_router = new AppRouter;

            app_router.on('route:getItems', function() {

            });

            app_router.on('route:showAll', function(){
                console.log("SHOWALL");
                 skillsview.render();
            });

            app_router.on('route:editItem', function(id){
                console.log("EDIT SKILL: "+id);
                editview.render(id);
            });

            app_router.on('route:saveItem', function(id){
                console.log("SAVED SKILL");
                skillsview.render(id);
            });
            app_router.on('route:deleteItem', function(id){
                console.log("DELETED SKILL");
                skillsview.render(id);
            });
```

However, I am getting a front end JS error when I try to send the id variable into my render function. The render function does not want to take any parameters I think. But if this is true, how can I send my router parameters to my render function where I fetch a Model using the id given from the router?

Comment: What is the JS error? What is `skillview` and `editview` and where do they get created?

Comment: its just an Unexpected identifier error. But the error is in the Backbone.js file so it must be something I'm doing to trigger it. The skillview and editview are just two Backbone.View's that I created before hand

Comment: Can you post the actual error? Without it, it is impossible to guess what the issue might be.